# Add active class to navbar element when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists, navbar

I have created with navbar, I haven't done much web development.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-light navbar-expand-md justify-content-center">
  <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html"><strong style="text-transform:uppercase">home</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html"><strong style="text-transform:uppercase">about</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="flights.html"><strong>FLIGHTS</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="hotels.html"><strong>HOTELS</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="holidays.html"><strong>HOLIDAYS</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="property.html"><strong>PROPERTY</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="car_hire.html"><strong>CAR HIRE</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This navbar is linked to at the top of all other pages to reduce repetition of code. Can someone help me with code so when menu item clicked "active" class is added to li element. This then triggers css.

CSS:

```
.nav-link.active {
  color: white;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use JavaScript/jQuery to add class to that element

Comment: There's also a pseudo-class named 'active' (see: [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) selector). Although the pseudo class names begin with `:` as opposed to `.`, you might want to consider naming it something else to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 6):

All you have to do is loop through the links, check if the current clicked link is the same as the current page, then set the active class and aria-current to that item.
Add this code to your javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach((link) => {
    if (link.href === window.location.href) {
        link.classList.add("active");
        link.setAttribute("aria-current", "page");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the exact complete code for your requirement in pure JavaScript. Hope it will help

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
    
if (links.length) {
  links.forEach((link) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      links.forEach((link) => {
          link.classList.remove('active');
      });
      e.preventDefault();
      link.classList.add('active');
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.nav-link.active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-light navbar-expand-md justify-content-center">
  <button
      class="navbar-toggler ml-1"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#collapsingNavbar2"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div
    class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100"
    id="collapsingNavbar2"
  >
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
          <strong style="text-transform: uppercase">home</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">
            <strong style="text-transform: uppercase">about</strong>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="flights.html">
          <strong>FLIGHTS</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="hotels.html">
            <strong>HOTELS</strong>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="holidays.html">
            <strong>HOLIDAYS</strong>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="property.html">
            <strong>PROPERTY</strong>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="car_hire.html">
            <strong>CAR HIRE</strong>
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This, doesn't actually work... Please explain what you added, so that OP can better understand what the issue was.

Comment: @Lissy93 it is working. And there are no issues. He just added JS code to add/remove class

Comment: Thank you for your response, This solution shows animation however the page is not changed.

Comment: If you're using `.forEach()`, you don't actually need to check `links.length`. That's implicit in how `.forEach()` works

Comment: @MatrixMC you can't have javascript change things between html pages. If you want the "page" to change, you have to implement that in javascript, which is a much larger task - unless it's already implemented in whatever framework you're using, in which case you can just remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: @SeanSutherland On the page loading I need the current pages navigation to change.  How could that be done? Using url?

Comment: @MatrixMC like I said, try removing the `e.preventDefault();` line from the code above. If doesn't work, then answering that is outside the scope of this question. I don't know how your app works, but you probably can't (or shouldn't) do it with javascript. You probably have to manually add the class to the html (or whatever generates it server-side) manually.

Comment: @SeanSutherland Thank you, When removing that line the css now shows but then moves to next page and is removed. This is for a small website where there are just a series of HTML files.

Comment: @MatrixMC then you just have to add the class manually to each page in the html file. No need to try and do it in javascript.

Comment: As compared to the other answer further down with use of `classlist`, you should make `home` active as as starter for the navigation. The landing page should be active.

Answer (score 3):

Use `classList`

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item").forEach((ele) =>
  ele.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document
      .querySelectorAll(".nav-item")
      .forEach((ele) => ele.classList.remove("active"));
    this.classList.add("active")
  })
);
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ><strong style="text-transform:uppercase">home</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ><strong style="text-transform:uppercase">about</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ><strong>FLIGHTS</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ><strong>HOTELS</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" ><strong>HOLIDAYS</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" ><strong>PROPERTY</strong></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" ><strong>CAR HIRE</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Not working. it adds active class to all <li>. I think the user might need to add only in clicked <li>.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I can't seem to get this solution to work..?

Comment: @MatrixMC, ah, I have updated the snippet with fix. Thanks you.

Comment: I build the li elements from js. With your code, the links get highlighted, but the link is not executed probably because of `e.preventDefault()`. Commenting it, the links work but the highlight works only for one ms and then disappears. So I should use in my special case the solution further down with the `id` selector and the pathname.

Answer (score 1):

Note: To use this each of your links need to have an id which need be be named the same as you page without the .html. For example if your page is named "index.html" then your link's id need to be "index".

```js
//active nav bar

//getting the link
const fullLink = window.location.pathname;
//isolating the page name
const activeLink = fullLink.split('/').pop().replace('.html', '');
//passing the page name through the function
function setActiveClass(elementId) {
    //getting the element that has the id of the page name
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    //checking if the element is valid
    if (element) {
        //adding class active to the element
        element.classList.add('active');
    }
}
//function getting called when page refresh of change of page and passing through the page name
setActiveClass(activeLink);
```

Comment: Can you please write a full example

Answer (score 0):

Using the code of [synthesizecode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77128664/1705829) further down, a full example of highlighting the selected nav.menu in vanilla js with 3 menu entries:

```
#test.html:
 <div id=div1></div>

 <script>
 
 for (var elem of ['index', "contact", 'imprint']) {
    var aref = document.createElement("a");
    aref.href = `${elem}.html`;
    aref.textContent = elem[0].toUpperCase() + elem.slice(1)
    document.getElementById('div1').append(aref)
    aref.style.padding='10px'
    aref.id = elem
}
const element = document.getElementById(window.location.pathname.split('/').pop().replace('.html', ''));
if (element) element.classList.add('active');
</script>
```

I need the final line **with** `if` because on the landingpage, there might be no `element`.

Answer (score -1):

Add following code in your JS:

```
 $(".nav-item").click(function() {  
    $(".nav-item").removeClass("active"); // This will remove active classes from all <li> tags
    $(this).addClass("active"); // This will add active class in clicked <li>   
  });
```

Comment: OP isn't using jQuery, why bring it in for something so simple?

Comment: Bootstrap removed jQuery a while back, in [version 5](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/06/16/bootstrap-5-alpha/). jQuery is generally considered outdated now, since most it's features can be done natively with ES5.